# Click on link, add text to textarea?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Let's say I have this javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addtext() {
    var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
    document.myform.description.value += newtext;
}
</script>
```

and I want to enable it so I can click on some html link that says "add text" and I want the text to be @ . $username . (using PHP to insert the username).  So when you click the "add text" link it'll put into the textarea @username.  It is hard to visualize and I'm not sure where to put the text and PHP exactly.  Thanks!

Textarea:

```
    <form Name ="myform" action="<?$posted = $_POST['description'];
    $object->post_tweet($posted); ?>" method="post">
    <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>

        <td class="2">
     <textarea name='description' class="color" COLS=84 ROWS=2 type="text" id="eBann" name="bannerURL" maxlength="100" size="60" onKeyUp="toCount('eBann','sBann','{CHAR} characters left',140);"></textarea>
    <br>
      <span id="sBann" class="minitext">140 characters left.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><BR><BR><BR>
<p><input type='submit' value='Tweet!' /><input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' /> </p>
</form>
```

This is what I want to do with the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addtext("@'. $twit->user->screen_name .'"); return false>reply</a>'
```

This gives me an error though (I added the addtext function too).

EDIT:  Got it!  I had mistakes with ' and " haha wow, stupid mistake.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ooh, tough one. This is a fantastic mish-mash of HTML, JavaScript, and PHP, isn't it?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addtext(text) {
    document.myform.description.value += text;
}
</script>

...

<a href="#" onclick="addtext('@<?php echo htmlspecialchars(addslashes($userName)) ?>'); return false"
  >reply</a>
```

Let's break that down: pretend `$userName` is `"TeaCast"`. Then the HTML that will get sent to the browser after the `<?php ?>` part has executed would look like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addtext('@TeaCast'); return false"
  >reply</a>
```

Ah!

Additional notes:

- The `href="#"` sets up a fake link that gives you the hand cursor but doesn't do anything.
- The `addslashes()` in the PHP code puts a backslash before any quotes.
- The `htmlspecialchars()` call ensures that a user name that contains weird characters like `'<'` or `'&'` won't mess up your page. Say some evil user who named themselves `"<script>alert('haha')</script>"` (yes, their user name is a snippet of HTML).

Comment: Ahh I had most of it you're right, I just needed to know where to put the PHP haha thanks John!

Comment: Oh well actually John, I wanted the name of the link to say "reply" instead of @username but have @username appear in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

John's answer works fine, but another alternative you can do is store the username in the javascript, such as:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var username = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars(addslashes($userName)) ?>';

function addtusername() {
    document.myform.description.value += "@" + username;
}
</script>

...

<a href="#" onclick="addusername(); return false">reply</a>
```

This way, you can use the variable username in the Javascript for other functions later, instead of using a bunch of php.

Comment: I was trying to use yours, but it still won't display it on the <textarea>, above I posted what it looks like, bear in mind it is intermixed with another javascript code (not sure if it matters)